# Pandas dataframe - TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to organize a dataset that I downloaded. Currently, I have a directory of images and an Excel spreadsheets with values for those images. I'm trying to combine those into a single dataframe that has one column for image filename and another for the actual file. Here's the code I have currently:

```
for filename in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\arnav\\Dataset\\Images"):
    new_filename = filename
    if(filename[0] == '.'):
        new_filename = filename[2:]
    picture = open(new_filename)
    filename_file.loc[filename_file['Filename'] == new_filename,'File'] = picture
```

The `filename_file` dataframe has 5500 rows with 2 columns, one for filename and one for the file. I managed to load the filenames in, so right now it has all zeros for the `File` column. When I run the loop I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 16, in <module>
    filename_file.loc[filename_file['Filename'] == new_filename,'File'] = picture
  File "C:\Users\arnav\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 190, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "C:\Users\arnav\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 604, in _setitem_with_indexer
    elif can_do_equal_len():
  File "C:\Users\arnav\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 554, in can_do_equal_len
    values_len = len(value)
TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()
```

I don't know why this is happening, can anyone help?

Comment: can you show what you want the output to look like? 5 rows will do.

Comment: I think you should use pandas `read_excel` to get data from excel files. Can you share your excel files example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign the file handler for your picture files, which fails due to internal checks by pandas using `len()`. If you want to assign the actual file contents to cells in the `File` column, you have to use `picture.read()`.

Sidenote: You might want to use a context manager when reading from files in Python, because otherwise you would leave a lot of unclosed IO objects.

```
for filename in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\arnav\\Dataset\\Images"):
    new_filename = filename
    if(filename[0] == '.'):
        new_filename = filename[2:]
    with open(new_filename, encoding='utf-8') as picture:
        filename_file.loc[filename_file['Filename'] == new_filename, 'File'] = picture.read()
```

Comment: When I try that, I get this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 251: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: This error can occur if your file's encoding method is different from your system's default encoding.  Explicitly defining the encoding type might help. Please try `with open(new_filename, encoding='utf-8') as picture:`